# Derby database primary key generate always as identity drop

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table MASTER with some columns.  When I originally set up the structure I created column ID as the primary key and an auto incrementing value (`generate always as identity start with 1, increment by 1`).

This worked fine but now trying to implement persistence I cannot get the persistence to commit to the database because of the primary key duplication exception.

I have tested on another small DB that if I have a standard non incrementing primary key column and use a SEQUENCE table everything works fine.

My problem is that I need to know how to drop the "generate always as identity...." but keep the primary key.  I cannot drop the column as it will corrupt all of my foreign keys and such.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a new table, with the structure you want, and copy the data from your existing table to your new table. In your new table, don't use the "generate always as identity", of course.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  I ended up giving up and rebuilding the table.  Too bad there is no way to edit the generation clause.  Oh well.